# i want to take the value of radius from the user and calculate area of circle in python

Tags: python-3.x

i want to take the value of radius 'r' from the user and use it in the function to get the area of the circle. But the output tells that r is not defined. How can i improve my solution.

```
class Area:   
    r=input("enter the value of radius : \n ")   
    def basic(self,r):
        area=str(2*3.14*r*r)
        print(area)
a=Area()
a.basic(r)
```

Comment: You should define r outside the scope of the class, say just before you use it in the call to basic.

Answer (score 0):

You should move `input` outside the class. This should work:

```
class Area:   
    def basic(self,r):
        area= 2*3.14 *r*r
        print(area)

r = int(input("enter the value of radius : \n "))   
a = Area()
a.basic(r)
```

Also, notice that you need to convert your input to an `int` so you can perform mathematical operations on it. Additionally, you don't need to convert the area to a string to print int.